# What does "Hide" and "Vessel" system apps on Motorola devices do?

Tags: system-apps, motorola

I have a Motorola Moto G Pure (XT2163DL) running Android 12. I came across a system app named Hide. Also, one named Vessel. I am curious as to what it does. What purpose do they serve?

Comment: System apps are usually device-specific. If you want to understand what a process is doing you can download it and analyze it statically in Ghidra or IdaPro. If your phone is rooted you could try to analyze it at run-time like opened files, network traffic, ...

Comment: Are you sure that they are System Apps?  Got to [Play Store](https://play.google.com/store/apps/) and search for those names. Scroll until you find teh same icon, then add the information above.